# Hide left sidebar when using Stack Overflow Teams

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is there an option to hide the left sidebar when using teams?

It's unnecessarily wide and I'd rather not have it on my screen at all.

For me, the team SO and the regular SO are two different sites, and I'd rather navigate between them using bookmarks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Edit: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This feature is now here, you can toggle the sidebar after you set the option "Hide left navigation" in `Settings -> Preferences`.

### Original answer:

**TL;DR:** There is no such option yet, but the SE dev team has planned its implementation.

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/371810) on Meta.SE says (among other things, I quoted the parts relevant to the question here):

> **Hide/collapse left nav** [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
>   One of the biggest concerns was the amount of space that is taken up by the left nav. We're currently working on making the left nav collapsible. If you collapse it, then the left nav stays collapsed. When you click on the hamburger to access it the left nav comes up as an overlay and will dismiss when you make a choice or click away. Plan is that this will be remembered per site. For example you can keep it open on SO.com, but keep it collapsed on other sites.

This feature has not been implemented yet, but as SE seems to deploy the left sidebar to all users in Early June, I assume this will get implemented soon:

> **Early June** - Deploy to Stack Overflow, MSO, and MSE for all users.

Comment: I suggest editing to clarify that this answer I assume is for the webapp? 
This is what I see in settings in the Windows App:
![2w38dft.png](http://i64.tinypic.com/2w38dft.png)

Comment: @boardtc This post is about [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), not MS Teams.

Comment: Oh, that's confusing, how should I have know that? Can the title be edited for clarification?

Comment: It's not confusing: (1) The question is tagged with [tag:stack-overflow-for-teams] where already a short hover over the tag shows that it's not "Stack Overflow for Microsoft Teams" but a "private Stack Overflow". (2) This is a meta site, which aims to hold public conversation about meta stuff like burning tags, reporting bugs, discuss features of the main site (SO.com in this case).

Comment: ok then, if it's the convention to rely on tags to categorise. I've told myself I should not have been confused it was not valid behaviour

Comment: Has this feature made it to MacOS clients?

Answer (score 3):

It's not even close to perfect but just works for me (web version) and save a lot of screen space.
Just use uBlock Chrome extension on left panel to remove it. (pick element on page to block - same way as Ads).
If you need the panel back, one-click turn uBlock off.